# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python, tkinter, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

```
 from tkinter import *
    import numpy as np
    from keras.preprocessing import image
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    root = Tk()
    root.title('2')
    root.geometry('340x340')

    las =Label(root, text='Укажите полный путь до файла!')
    las.place(x=0, y=10)
    e_get = Entry(root)
    e_get.place(x=180,y=10)

    btn_start =Button(root, text = "Начать")
    btn_start.bind('<Button1>', lambda even: rage(e_get))
    def rage(x):
        img_path = x
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(28, 28), grayscale=True)
        plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
        plt.show

    # Преобразуем изображением в массив numpy
        x = image.img_to_array(img)

    # Инвертируем и нормализуем изображение
        x = 255 - x
        x /= 255
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

        json_file = open("mnist_model_conv.json", "r")
        loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
        json_file.close()
        loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
        loaded_model.load_weights("mnist_model_conv.h5")

        loaded_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])


        prediction = loaded_model.predict(x)
        print(np.argmax(prediction))


    root.mainloop()
```

Подскажите в чем ошибка при запуске вылетает(использую thensorflow)

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: по запросу в гугл `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'` много ссылок на гитхабовский багтрекер.  Все решения попробовали? Кому-то помогло просто сменить директорию перед запуском.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n проблема  том, что ошибку стало выдавать только после того как я обернул распознование в функции и начал ее вызывать